# Confusion about proof of every asymmetric relation being an irreflexive relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let R be asymmetric. We need to show R is irreflexive.

So by definition, we assume:

1. (x,y)∈R⟹(y,x)∉R

Definition of irreflexivity:

2. (x,x)∉R

Let's do an indirect proof, so we assume:

3. (x,x)∈R

Use Modus Ponens on 1 and 3, we get (x,x)∉R - contradiction. QED

The modus ponens step is where I get confused: the antecedent of the conditional is (x,y)∈R, but we are replacing it with (x,x)∈R instead. If the variables are different, how could we do that?

I suspect I may have confusion about the fundamental meaning of a variable, because by intuition this seems like a legitimate step, but I want to make sure I get it 100%. Could anyone help please?

Comment: I've given you a complete formal proof that makes everything explicit and should clear your doubts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly point out, your problem comes from not understanding variables properly. It is invalid to use $x,y$ without stating what it is.

Given any asymmetric relation $R$ on a collection $S$:

For any $x,y \in S$:

$(x,y) \in R \rightarrow (y,x) \notin R$.

For any $x \in S$:

$(x,x) \in R \rightarrow (x,x) \notin R$.

If $(x,x) \in R$:

$(x,x) \notin R$.

Contradiction.

Therefore $(x,x) \notin R$.

Therefore $R$ is irreflexive.

Comment: Is there any particular explanation/steps needed to jump from (x,y)∈R→(y,x)∉R to (x,x)∈R→(x,x)∉R? Or is it just like Dominik said that, since we did not assume that x≠y, it is a legitimate step?

Comment: @DanielMak: We cannot refer to objects without using references, here we have given the names "$x$" and "$y$" to any arbitrary objects you pick from $S$. Different references may refer to the same object. The meaning of universal quantification "for any ..." does not restrict it to being different from all previously considered objects, so indeed we do not require $x,y$ to be unequal when we claim that for any $x,y \in S$ we have $(x,y) \in R \rightarrow (y,x) \notin R$.

Comment: @DanielMak: The reason I found Dominik's explanation inadequate is that you must know how exactly $x,y$ are defined. They are not simply arbitrary or whatever. They are arbitrary objects from $S$.

Comment: Thank you, your explanation of references and universal quantification really cleared things up

Comment: @DanielMak: You're welcome, and I am very glad I could clear it up for you! Keep at it (learning mathematics in your free time) and your efforts will pay off! =)

Answer (score 1):

x and y are arbitrary variables. Just because they are denoted by different letters does not mean that they must have different values.

Comment: What do you mean by value? Their references?
Also would you mind taking a look at my comment to user254665 below please? The rules of formal logic does not seem to allow what you said, i.e. if you use universal instantiation ∀x(x,y)∈R⟹(y,x)∉R cannot become (x,x)∈R⟹(x,x)∉R. So how would you do it in a formal proof?

Comment: With "same values" i mean that x = y. This is essentially what is happening in the proof: You take an arbitrary x and then set y = x.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "For all x and for all y..."  you are NOT assuming that x and y are not names for the same thing.

Comment: this is pretty much the same answer which was already given, so it's a bit redundant - you could for example add a formal prove of the statement to your answer?

Comment: @user254665 Given what you said that does make the whole thing sensible. But if we are to formalise the entire proof, and apply universal instantiation to ∀x(x,y)∈R⟹(y,x)∉R, you cannot just instantiate it to (x,x)∈R⟹(x,x)∉R and cite the reason you gave. So how would you do so in a formal proof?

Also, would you mind recommending readings for relevant readings on variables which explains these kinds of things please? I feel that my understanding on the meanings of variables is shaky.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the others answers. This is your property :

$$\forall (x,y)\in E^2, ( (x,y)\in R \Rightarrow (y,x) \not\in R )$$

So this imply that

$$\forall t, ( (t,t)\in R \Rightarrow (t,t) \not\in R )$$

But you have that

$$\forall t \in E, ( (t,t) \not\in R \vee (t,t)\in R) $$

Hence

$$\forall t \in E, ( (t,t) \not\in R \vee ( (t,t) \in R \Rightarrow (t,t)\not\in R) \vee (t,t)\in R  ) $$

So by modus ponens, you get

$$\forall t \in E, ( (t,t) \not\in R \vee (t,t)\not\in R) $$

And this is

$$\forall t \in E , (t,t) \not\in R  $$

Comment: How did you proceed from step 1 to step 2 and 3? I can't see how step 1 and 2 are equivalent

Comment: @DanielMak :  For step 1 to step 2, you have an implication that is true for all elements of a set $X$, and you have a subset $Y$ of $X$, then it's clear that the implication is true for all elements of $Y$ too. Here the set $X$ is $E^2$, and the subset $Y$ is $\{ (x,y) \in E^2 : x=y \}$ The elements of $Y$ are exactly the elements of the form $(t,t), t\in E$

Comment: Step 3 is independant and always true, no matter what $R$ is. Indeed, it just say $$"(t,t) \in R" \text{ or } "\text{not}  (t,t) \in R"$$